# Make a pygame resizable window that can be snapped to the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I've created a simple screen with:

```py
user_display = pg.display.Info()

win = pg.display.set_mode((user_display.current_w, user_display.current_h), pg.RESIZABLE)
```

This creates a window that can be resized, which sets itself to the user's current screen size.  The problem with this is that the window's location appears off to the corner.  Ideally, the desired effect would be what happens when the fullscreen icon on the top of the window was clicked, by default.  Is there a way to set this so that the screen is automatically snapped to the top?

Comment: Do you mean like a full-screen window, so no border or controls are visible?  The above code creates a window with content-size the same as the screen, it can only be placed "off to the corner" and still show the controls.  Your operating system / window manager  prioritises showing the controls.

Comment: @Kingsley I want the screen to be maximized but still be resizable.  Obviously the user could maximize the window by pressing the maximize button, but I want this to occur by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're talking about maximizing the window, not fullscreen mode.

If you only care about Windows, you can use the Win32-API to maximize the window (using the `win32gui` module):

```
import pygame
import win32gui
import win32con

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)
    win32gui.ShowWindow(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow(), win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)

    ball = pygame.Rect(0, 300, 32, 32)
    dir = 1

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()

        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((e.w,e.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
                ball = pygame.Rect(0, int(e.h/2), 32, 32)

        if not screen.get_rect().contains(ball):
            dir *= -1
        ball.move_ip(dir, 0)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color("dodgerblue"), ball)
        pygame.display.flip()
main()
```

If you want to maximize the window on other systems, like Linux, I have no idea, but you could wrap your pygame window in a tkinter window and maximze that:

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
import os

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    embed = tk.Frame(root, width = 800, height = 600)
    embed.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
    root.state('zoomed')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)

    ball = pygame.Rect(0, 300, 32, 32)
    dir = 1

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()

        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((e.w,e.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
                ball = pygame.Rect(0, int(e.h/2), 32, 32)

        if not screen.get_rect().contains(ball):
            dir *= -1
        ball.move_ip(dir, 0)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color("dodgerblue"), ball)
        pygame.display.flip()
        root.update()      
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The position of the window can be set by setting the environment variable `SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS` before initializing a window by [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode). For instance

```py
import os
import pygame

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(20, 20)

pygame.init()
user_display = pg.display.Info()
win = pg.display.set_mode((user_display.current_w, user_display.current_h), pg.RESIZABLE)
```

See also [`SettingWindowPosition`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135928/pygame-display-position)

---

If you want to change the position of the window in-program, then you have to set the position first and recreate the display surface by `pygame.display.set_mode`.
See [How to move a no frame pygame windows when user click on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674156/how-to-move-a-no-frame-pygame-windows-when-user-click-on-it/57681853#57681853).