# Can I maximize the pygame Window without hiding title bar?

Tags: python, pygame, fullscreen, titlebar

I am currently programming a small game in pygame. Is there any way that I can set the pygame window to the maximum size of the screen, but still get the title bar to close the window? I would like to have the whole thing very dynamic, so adapting to the display size of the monitor

I already tried the pygame.display.set_mod() method and passed pygame.FULLSCREEN as parameter. However I have no title bar there anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: If you only care about Windows, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62037611/142637) answer. But the other tkinter stuff no longer works if you use a newer pygame version that uses SDL 2.

Comment: If you call [`set_mode(size=(0, 0))`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), you'll get a title bar and a maximised screen.

Answer (score -1):

One of the easiest ways to keep the title bar in your window is to use Tkinter. Tkinter is a module that comes pre-installed with Python, and it can give you the size of the screen you're using which you can put into the pygame function.

This is how you could use it:

```
import pygame
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()

pygame.init()

# Set size of window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])

done = False
while done == False:
    # Check for closing of window
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

pygame.quit()
```