# Pygame, Resize and Move window with no frame?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pygame, window

Hi have made my own custom title bar so i added the NOFRAME flag. Is there a way for me to still able to move and resize the window (by dragging the edges)?

Comment: [How to move a no frame pygame windows when user click on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674156/how-to-move-a-no-frame-pygame-windows-when-user-click-on-it/57681853#57681853)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of moving the screen (for windows, else use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674156/how-to-move-a-no-frame-pygame-windows-when-user-click-on-it/57681853#57681853)), but not resizing (without flickering).

I used Rabbid76's answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674156/how-to-move-a-no-frame-pygame-windows-when-user-click-on-it/57681853#57681853) and edited to work for python 2.0.

This line is what moves the window  `windll.user32.MoveWindow(hwnd, -coordinates[0], -coordinates[1], w, h, False)` you can read more about in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow)

here is the full code example:

```
# coding : utf-8
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from os import environ
from ctypes import windll

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
window_size_x, window_size_y = 720, 360

info = pygame.display.Info()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_size_x, window_size_x), pygame.NOFRAME)


def moveWin(coordinates):
    # the handle to the window
    hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window']

    # user32.MoveWindow also recieves a new size for the window
    w, h = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
    windll.user32.MoveWindow(hwnd, -coordinates[0], -coordinates[1], w, h, False)


def main():
    run = True
    pressed = False
    start_pos = (0, 0)
    window_coords = [0 ,0]
    moveWin(window_coords)
    while run:
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    run = False

            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pressed = True
                start_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if pressed:
                    new_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    window_coords[0] += start_pos[0] - new_pos[0]
                    window_coords[1] += start_pos[1] - new_pos[1]
                    moveWin(window_coords)
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pressed = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```